# Retrofit - delete was null but response body type was declared as non-null

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, android-architecture-components

So, After I delete a specific topic in my API it throws to me this error message

> deleteTopic was null but response body type was declared as non-null

The topic is succefully deleted but in my client, this response resolves in my catch block somehow

### Service

```
@DELETE("topics/{id}")
    suspend fun deleteTopic(@Path("id") id:String)
```

### Repo

```
override suspend fun deleteTopic(id: String): Resource<Unit> {
        return Resource.Success(RetrofitClient.webservice.deleteTopic(id))
    }
```

### ViewModel

```
fun deleteTopic(id:String) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        try {
            emit(repo.deleteTopic(id))
        }catch (e:Exception){
            emit(Resource.Failure(e))
        }
    }
```

For some reason I succefully delete the topic in my server, but when it returns to my client, it goes to the catch and returns this exception that I mentioned above, the response is a 204 not content, but how can I fix this response to sucefully tell me that this operation has done correctly ?

I'm confused, I have readed into github that I must retunr `Response<Unit>` but I'm still confused why I should do this, it also says taht returning that will prevent my 4xx return codes to be thrown

Answer (score 11):

Using `Response<Unit>` works

Reference: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3075#issuecomment-564556949

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that your deletion endpoint does return empty body response (just { }). If you can, change your backend source to not do so. Otherwise, you can prob add a custom converter to handle 4xx status codes properly.

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554#issuecomment-178633697

Comment: Sorry but I cant change the server since this is a task that I need to perform

Comment: I have added the converter but the problem persists

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point on `body.contentLength() == 0`, maybe your response does have some content? Have you also tried using this https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554#issuecomment-212941985 converter?